# Passing a python2.7 string with internal null characters to c++

Tags: python, c++, swig, python-2.x, cpython

Is there a way to pass a python2.7 string with a null character in the middle (such as `foo\0bar`) to c++ code in swig bindings?

The [python C bindings](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/string.html#c.PyString_AS_STRING) provide two functions: `PyString_AsString` and `PyString_AsStringAndSize`, but both functions return null terminated strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs for `PyString_AsStringAndSize` say, it preserves internal null characters unless you pass `NULL` for `length`. Which you're obviously not going to do (since you can't do anything with a string with internal null characters if you don't know is length).

It does ensure a null terminator at the end whether you want one or not, but if that's not acceptable, it's easy to deal with: just decrement the length it returns by one.

So, unless you're worried about the potential performance cost of Python copying the buffer just to add a null terminator that you don't need (in which case I wouldn't worry—most ways of creating strings, you're already going to have the terminator in the buffer), there shouldn't be any problem here.

---

To prove it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

from ctypes import *

PyString_AsStringAndSize = pythonapi.PyString_AsStringAndSize
PyString_AsStringAndSize.argtypes = [
    py_object, POINTER(POINTER(c_int8)), POINTER(c_ssize_t)]
PyString_AsStringAndSize.restype = c_int

s = 'foo\0bar'
buf = POINTER(c_int8)()
size = c_ssize_t()

res = PyString_AsStringAndSize(s, byref(buf), byref(size))
print res
print size.value
bufa = cast(buf, POINTER(c_int8 * size.value))
print bufa.contents[:size.value]
print repr(''.join(chr(c) for c in bufa.contents[:size.value]))
```

The output is:

```
0
7
[102, 111, 111, 0, 98, 97, 114]
'foo\x00bar'
```

Exactly what you wanted, right?

(And in C++, you won't have to do all that annoying stuff to work around `ctypes` that I did, first using `int8` instead of `char` to prevent it from being too smart and making a string, and then casting it to an array because pointer arithmetic isn't allowed.)